# I want to select certain columns from two tables, and create a join into a third table

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables f_com and d_summary, I have selected below fields from the two tables and want to join the tables on the key into a third table.

```sql
    Create table temp.merge

    Select D_AH_MH_SUMMARY_KEY, MID_KEY, CHID_KEY, ACTIVITY_DT,
     SPONSOR_STATE, RESPONSE_TYPE, IS_CURRENT from f_com 

    Select d_ah_mh_summary_key, activity_name, activity_type, 
    activity_dt from d_summary 
    Join on f_com.D_AH_MH_SUMMARY_KEY = d_summary.d_ah_mh_summary_key
    group by D_AH_MH_SUMMARY_KEY, MID_KEY, CHID_KEY, ACTIVITY_DT,
    SPONSOR_STATE, RESPONSE_TYPE, IS_CURRENT, activity_name, activity_type, activity_dt
```

Expecting a merged table `temp.merge` with the selected fields from the two tables, merged on the `f_com.D_AH_MH_SUMMARY_KEY = d_summary.d_ah_mh_summary_key`

Comment: The first question is _WHY?_ Unless this is a temp table inside a stored procedure, you are going to have a maintenance nightmare. Having said that, your query is malformed. There are a number of problems. For example, the `GROUP BY` clause is not necessary since you don't have aggregate values. The `GROUP BY` is used with functions like `SUM(column)` or `COUNT(column)`.

Comment: @daShier: Yes it is a temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) statement for the same.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_merge AS
SELECT 
    f_com.D_AH_MH_SUMMARY_KEY AS f_com_D_AH_MH_SUMMARY_KEY, 
    f_com.MID_KEY, 
    f_com.CHID_KEY, 
    f_com.ACTIVITY_DT AS f_com_ACTIVITY_DT,
    f_com.SPONSOR_STATE, 
    f_com.RESPONSE_TYPE, 
    f_com.IS_CURRENT
    d_summary.d_ah_mh_summary_key, 
    d_summary.activity_name, 
    d_summary.activity_type, 
    d_summary.activity_dt
FROM f_com 
JOIN ON d_summary ON f_com.D_AH_MH_SUMMARY_KEY = d_summary.d_ah_mh_summary_key
GROUP BY f_com.D_AH_MH_SUMMARY_KEY, MID_KEY, CHID_KEY, ACTIVITY_DT,
 SPONSOR_STATE, RESPONSE_TYPE, IS_CURRENT, activity_name, activity_type, activity_dt
```

Note: As mentioned in comment, if you don't need `GROUP BY` clause just remove it.